# L'utilisation de "lequel"

Tags: pronoms-relatifs

Est-ce que c'est correct d'utiliser le pronom relatif dans le cas suivant? "J'avais le cours de français lequel a fini à 13 heures."

Answer (score 6):

L'article défini devant cours indique qu'il s'agit d'un cours de français précis parmi d'autres. Dans ce cas, ***qui*** est utilisé pour préciser de quel cours il s'agit; on ne peut pas utiliser ***lequel*** dans ce cas :

> J'avais **le** cours de français **qui** a fini à 13 heures (, pas celui qui finissait à 11 heures).

En revanche, on peut utiliser ***lequel*** pour apporter une information nouvelle :

> J'avais **un** cours de français, **lequel** a fini à 13 heures.

mais la tournure est recherchée.

On peut aussi utiliser un article indéfini puis apporter une précision :

> J'avais **un** cours de français **qui** a fini à 13 heures.

Souvent, on n'utilise pas d'article et on sépare les deux propositions :

> J'avais cours de français. Il a fini à 13 heures.

Comment: +10! Ha bien vu! L'article défini est déjà là!

Comment: Je ne suis pas certain que l'article défini exclut l'utilisation de `lequel`. Je n'emploie évidemment jamais cette formulation, mais ça ne me paraît pas incorrect de dire : `J'étais au (à + le) cours de français, lequel a fini à 13 heures`. De même, l'article indéfini ne me semble pas interdire l'utilisation de `qui` : `J'avais un cours de français qui a fini à 13 heures`. Tout cela n'est que mon impression sans aucune vérification.

Comment: @Destal Je ne sais pas s'il y a une règle mais je trouve aussi que *j'étais au cours de français, lequel a fini à 13 heures* passe mieux que la phrase originale.

Comment: Il faut dire que le début de la phrase originale, `J'avais le cours de français`, même sans la suite, semble déjà très étrange pour un francophone.

Comment: @Destal : Est-ce que cela le fait mieux en le graissant + capitale à l'initiale : *j'avais **Le** cours de...* ?

Comment: @aCOSwt Oui mais dans ce cas on change l'intention, d'ailleurs beaucoup de Français diraient *J'avais **The** (prononcé "zeu") cours de...*. Était-ce ce que voulait dire l'OP ? J'avais plutôt compris que c'était une erreur de formulation de sa part, en souhaitant dire quelque chose comme *j'étais en cours de français* ou *j'avais cours de français*. Mais en cherchant bien on peut trouver des raisons d'utiliser *j'avais le cours de français* et que ça paraissent naturel, c'est juste la phrase sans contexte qui ne paraît pas naturelle.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct grammatically; a comma is needed after « français ».

- J'avais le cours de français, lequel a fini à 13 heures.

However, that's formal language, that you might use for instance if it were in a reply to a judge in court. In speaking with friends you'd say rather something like this.

- J'avais le cours de français, il a fini à 13 heures.
- J'avais le cours de français, qui a fini à 13 heures.

There is a slight pause after the comma (reading and speech), otherwise you are not saying quite the same thing. The reason for the comma is that the relative pronoun introduces a descriptive clause when the comma is used; when the clause is a determining clause, that is a clause that says which French course it is (that course that end at 1 PM and not another one) then you use no comma.

Comment: +1 Oui! Hors usage formel, il s'avère parfois utile pour lever une ambiguïté : *je lisais un livre du prof, lequel / qui est vraiment ennuyeux*.

Comment: @aCOSwt Est-ce que ça lève l'ambiguïté ? Lequel est ennuyeux ? *Je lisais un livre du prof, lesquels sont vraiment ennuyeux...* ;-)